# Winform ClientSize exceeds screen dimensions after Maximize w/ no border

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code to toggle between a WindowState of Normal (with a Sizable border style) and Maximized (with a border style of None).

```
if (WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
}
else
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}
```

I am also dynamically adjusting the layout of some controls on the form after the change.  I have found that the `ClientSize.Width` and `ClientSize.Height` values exceed the actual monitor resolution in the Maximized/No border state (Client size: 1936x1216, Actual monitor resolution: 1920x1200).  This results in some of the controls being placed beyond out of bounds.

Is there an easy way to make sure the form does not exceed the screens limits (other than manually checking the screen size and forcing the form to that size)?

Comment: That's entirely normal, the maximum allowed window size is the monitor size plus the borders.  Which ensures that when you maximize the window, you only see the client area and not the borders.  So when you remove the borders, you'll now inevitably end up with a client area that's too large.  Just delete this code, it isn't necessary.  If you want overlap the user's taskbar, a detail that belongs in the question, then you'll have to handle the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I do not have any issues with the taskbar.  I found that turning off the border first results in the desired behaviour.

Comment: Then there is no point to this code.  Be sure to remove it, changing the FormBorderStyle can have a lot of undesirable side-effects.  As you found out.

Comment: I do not understand the comment that there is no point to this code.  This section of code is in a method called under certain conditions and is doing exactly what I need (toggling the application between a normal, sizable view and full screen).  Perhaps there is a better way to do it, but just removing this code would prevent the application from responding properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be resolvable by inverting the order of the maximize and border style change operations.  If the border is turned off prior to maximizing the screen, the form `ClientSize` values will match the monitor size exactly.

Working code:

```
if (WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```